# Nextjs router.beforepopstate not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

```
//_.app.js   
 import React from 'react';
    import App, { Container } from 'next/app';
    import Layout from '../components/layout';
    import Head from 'next/head';
    import Router from 'next/router';

    class MyApp extends App {
      componentDidMount() {
        // Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', (url) => {
        //   alert('route changes');
        // });
        Router.beforePopState(({ url, as, opts }) => {
          alert('before pop state');
          return true;
        });
      }

      render() {
        const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

        return (
          <Container>
            <Head>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
            </Head>
            <Layout>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Layout>
          </Container>
        );
      }
    }

    export default MyApp;
```

Hi can I ask why when I press the browser back and forward button the router.beforepopstate is not firing at all..?
1. I am trying to implement something which is press the back button I will do something first before going to the next page.
2. But when I press back button nothing happens at all only the routechangestart got trigger when i use router.push...
If any of you guys can really help me out I will be very grateful..